# JavaFX: ImageView cannot load image that was created by the program itself. Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, illegalargumentexception

I am attempting to create a program in which the user selects an image from a different folder on their computer and JavaFX copies that image into the project directory for future use. A new folder is created that will store the newly created image file. This is essentially the code for selecting and copying the image into the project directory:

```
Stage window = (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Select Image File");
File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(window);

//Creates a new directory for the new calendar that the user wants to create
File file = new File("src/DefaultUser/" + nameField.getText() + "/");
file.mkdir();

//Creates a new file name with logo as the name, but keeping the extension the same
int index = selectedFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
String ext = selectedFile.getName().substring(index);

//Stored in newFileName
String newFileName = "logo" + ext;

File newFile = new File(file.getPath() + "/" + newFileName);

//Copies the selected file into the project src folder, with newFileName as the new file name
Files.copy(selectedFile.toPath(), newFile.toPath());
```

Then the program moves onto a different scene and thus a different controller actually loads the image into an ImageView. I know that the path for the Image works properly but for whatever reason the program cannot find the image file to load it into the ImageView.

Here is essentially the code used for that:

```
image.setImage(new Image("DefaultUser/" + imagePath));
```

Don't worry about what imagePath is in this case because I am absolutely positive it paths to the correct location for the newly created image file. This is because if I close the JavaFX program and rerun it, the image loads properly.

At first, I thought it was because it took time for the image to be copied into the project directory but I checked that the file actually existed within the code and it did so this is apparently not the case. I tried using Thread.sleep() to delay the program a bit so that the code would potentially have more time to copy the file but it still threw the same error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found`

The strangest part about this is that the program works perfectly fine, it's just that I have to restart the JavaFX program for it to be able to detect the image file, even though I know it exists. Is there something weird about JavaFX and creating new files and accessing them within the same program? I am truly lost. Thank you so much in advance for any help and I'm sorry if this doesn't give enough information because I don't want to have to explain the whole project.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: A resource is a static thing, that is in the class path of your program. You can't copy things to class path during runtime, and expect it to be available. That's just not how class loaders (which is used to load resources) work. Instead, make directory in the current users home directory or so, and load images from there, as *normal files*.

Comment: Also note that `src` is a *source* folder: it's not part of the classpath and typically isn't even present at runtime. It makes zero sense to try to create an "on the fly resource" there. What's likely happening is that between closing the program and running it again, your IDE is deploying the file that was created to the build folder, which is why it appears to work when you restart the application.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense thank yall so much I'll try making those changes.

Comment: That worked! I just moved the DefaultUser folder into the project folder and not the src folder and everything worked fine. Thank yall so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just like haraldK and James_D said in the comments putting stuff in the src folder is generally a bad idea. I solved the issue by moving the folder out into the project directory instead.